# Takes forever for debugger to attach

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, android-emulator

I am trying to access the eclipse debugger perspective; however, when I tried to run my simple app in debug, the debugger took forever (like 10 hours) and still wasn't sucessfully attached.  What was wrong?  Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Please provide more details. What platform, what sort of app, written in which language?

Comment: Try to add more details. Debug perspective usually opens by default when you launch an app in debug, or alternatively you'll be prompt for that. BTW you can open it from: Window-> Open Perspective-> Debug . Eclipse isn't very fast and you may wait several seconds before the debug starts(depends on your pc's performances)

Comment: I am using Galileo on the latest Android SDK on Win 7.  I am not sure if Galileo's outdated so it's no longer supported or what, but it used to work with earlier Android SDK on Vista.

Comment: @Jason Ching: Android emulator is very slow. It takes even several minutes before starting. Consider testing using real devices or try virtualization on your x86 machine http://www.android-x86.org/ .

Comment: I think if it took 10 hours something else is broken.